# Android widget only being updated when resized

Tags: android, android-widget

Currently when I first place the widget on the homescreen nothing happens. When I resize it, it look like the on update is called. Anyone know why this is?

Comment: what do you want to happen? onUpdate() get called because you are resizing the widget. You can have different views for different sizes, or refresh, etc. not your place to ask why, this is how google designed it. what are you expecting? rewrite your question

Comment: I would want the onUpdate to be called when the widget is first created, but it is not being called for some reason. It is only being called when the widget is resized.

Comment: theres a function that gets called when you drop it. did you read the documentation?

Answer (score 1):

Place your logic inside the `onEnabled()` function of your `AppWidgetProvider`.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/appwidget/AppWidgetProvider.html#onEnabled(android.content.Context)